# fa-fa displays a flag icon. Why is this happening?

Tags: font-awesome

When the class name is specified as "fa-fa" it displays flag icon. However this is not documented in font-awesome. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fa` is an alias for `fontawesome` and it is documented [here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/font-awesome/) to show the flag.